# Which text editor can be able to properly display the storage files created by the CodenameOne Netbeans plugin in linux?

Tags: linux, netbeans, codenameone

Which Linux text editor can be used to view the hidden files created by the **CodenameOne** simulator? I have tried the default **Gedit** and **Notepadqq** but the text appears gibberish while on Windows it is legible even with the default note.exe app in a human-readable way. I am running Netbeans 10 on Ubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This highly depends on the file you are editing but if you are editing the preferences file then you would break it. It's a binary file that shouldn't be edited with text editing software. Some characters that are visible on the Linux editors might be hidden on notepad. But they would still be there.

Comment: Actually, I mainly wanted to view instead of having to output in the console as a quick way to check if content, say a string, was written to persistent storage or filesystem in the simulator .cn1 folder.